# Smooth maps between two smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

For any topological space $M$ , let $C(M)$ denote the vector space of continuous functions $ f : M \to \mathbf{R} $ . If  $ F: M \to N $ be a continuous map between smooth manifolds $ M $ and $N$ . Define $F^* : C(N) \to C(M) $ by $F^*(f) = f \circ F$ . Show that if $ F^*( C^\infty(N)) \subset C^\infty(M)$ then $F$ is smooth .

I think this might be a wrong question. If $M=N=\mathbf{R}$ and $F(x)=|x|$ and take $f$ to be a constant function then we have a contradiction..Also I am unable to prove the statement..Need some help..

Comment: You're not allowed to choose just a single $f$, it has to work for _all_ $f\in C^\infty(N)$.

Comment: That's right. But I can't find a $f$ such that $f \circ F$ is not smooth for this particular $F$

Comment: Also I am unable to prove the statement..

Comment: For that particular $F$, you can take $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to just be the identity function.

Comment: Oh yes yes..can you plese prove the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard exercise. Sketch of proof:

If under a local coordinates, $F = (F_1, \cdots F_n)$, you need only to know that $F_i$ are smooth. Note $F_i = F^* y_i$, where $(y_1, \cdots y_n)$ is a local coordinates of $N$. So you are almost done as $y_i$ are local smooth functions. But to use the condition to need to use global smooth functions. So the use of a bump function is needed.

I will leave the details to you.

Comment: Thanks..If $F^*$ is an isomorphism and $F$ is a homeomorphism then why $F$ is a smooth map?

Comment: we need only that $ F^*( C^\infty(N)) \subset C^\infty(M)$ to conclude that $F$ is smooth. @Saikat

Comment: Yes.Under an isomorphism smooth maps goes to smooth maps...So $F$ is smooth..Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean $F^* :C(N)\to C(M)$ is isomorphic or $F^*:C^\infty(N)\to C^\infty(M)$ is isomorphic?

Comment: $F^* : C(N) \to C(M)$ is isomophic.

Comment: Note that $F$ is smooth if and only if $F^* : C^\infty (N)\subset C^\infty(M)$ so $F^* :C(N) \to C(M)$ does not imply that $F$ is smooth. @Saikat

Comment: Given that $F$ is a homeomorphism and $F^*$ is an isomorphism.I have to show that $F$ is a diffeomorphism..If I can show that $F$ is smooth then I am done ( because then I am able to show that inverse of $F$ is smooth)..

Comment: This is not true. There are homeomorphic smooth manifolds which are not diffeomorphic. So what you stated cannot be proved. @Saikat, unless by isomorphism of $F^*$ you really mean $F^* : C^\infty(N) \to C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: Can you give some examples where $M$ and $N$ are not diffeomorphic but $F^*$ is an isomrphism.

Comment: There are indeed quite a lot, though not intuitive: there are 28 different smooth structure on $\mathbb S^7$, so the identity map $F : \mathbb S^7 \to \mathbb S^7$ between any two of them will be an example @Saikat